# Localization on `get-started` page in Careers displays multiple language messages

Tags: bug, jobs

When creating new account on *careers.stackoverflow.com* not all localization strings are in English. Error message under *Personal Statement* displays in German.

My browser settings:

- language - `pl-PL`
- browser - `Chrome 46.0.2490.86 m`

[image]

Comment: Can this be closed as off-topic/relevant elseware and/or migrated to Meta SO?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 where should this kind of tickets go? Nor SO nor Careers doesn't have separate ticketing systems.

Comment: no other SE site has a Careers subsite. Meta SO is for anything related to specifically the Stack Overflow site. That includes Careers.

Comment: hmm, indeed. And bugs about _Careers_ appears on both of them. Maybe somebody else will check it, you can always flag question.

Comment: This is the right place to report it. I'll look into this tomorrow.